How to prevent `maven-metadata.xml` from updating with every build in Gradle Maven publishing?
I am working on a Gradle project where I publish artifacts to a JFrog Artifactory repository(this repository is a generic repository, not a maven repository) using Maven publishing. However, I am facing an issue where the maven-metadata.xml file in the repository is updated with every build, causing the latest version to always reflect the most recent build, regardless of whether it is a release build, development build, or feature branch build.
I want to ensure that only stable release builds update the latest version in maven-metadata.xml. Development and feature branch builds should not affect it.
Here's what I tried so far, but none of them worked:

Using Snapshot Versions:
I added -SNAPSHOT to the version for non-release builds, hoping that the repository would treat them differently:
gradle -Pversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT publish


Disabling the GenerateModuleMetadata Task:
I also tried skipping the generateMetadataFileForMavenCatalogPublication task by disabling it during development builds:
tasks.named("generateMetadataFileForMavenCatalogPublication") {
    enabled = project.findProperty("buildType") != "dev"
}


Skipping All GenerateModuleMetadata Tasks:
Next, I skipped all tasks of type GenerateModuleMetadata to ensure that no metadata files would be generated:
tasks.withType<GenerateModuleMetadata> {
    enabled = project.findProperty("buildType") != "dev"
}


Adding skip-metadata to Artifactory URL:
I also tried appending skip-metadata to the Artifactory URL, as suggested in some references.


Here's how I'm publishing the project:
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("artifactory-url")
            credentials(PasswordCredentials::class)
        }
    }
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("mavenCatalog") {
            from(components["java"])
        }
    }
}

Is there anything that I'm missing or doing wrong?

Why do you care what information is present in maven-metadata.xml ?

@JFabianMeier I have a custom plugin that checks for the latest release version of the artifact. If it's updated with all sorts of builds, my plugin will always fail as it only checks for the latest release.

Have a look at https://www.mojohaus.org/versions/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-releases-mojo.html

This won't help right, the problem still is that the latest version of the library is getting replaced with every build. I want to control that.

You are using MavenPublication.  As per its documentation does not provide a way to not publish metadata.
Given you want to treat the artifacts as maven artifacts, you could explore deploying SNAPSHOTS/development builds to a different repository, or relook at using generic repository.

Are there no other ways? I don't want to switch to a different repository.
